# Regarding Urysohn's metrization theorem proof

Tags: general-topology

At Munkres' topology, he showed two different proof of Urysohn's metrization theorem.

In the first version of the proof, he tried to construct some continuous function $F$ from a given space $X$ which we want to show it is metrizable to $\mathbb R^\omega$ in the product topology.

($F(x) = ( f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x), ...)$ where each $f_i(x)$ is continuous on $X$.

and then showed that for any open $U$ in $X$, $F(U)$ is open in $\mathbb R^\omega$.

But I took a different approach that for any basis element $B$ of $ \mathbb R^\omega$ in the product topology, $F^{-1} (B)$ is open in $X$.

Let $y \in F(X)$, then $y = ( f_1(x), f_2(x), f_3(x), ...) \in V$ for given open set $V$.
Then since $F(X)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^\omega$, there exists a basis element $B=\prod  X_\alpha$, contained in $V$, for finitely many $i$, $X_i \neq \mathbb R$.

Then it suffices to show that $F^{-1}(B)$ is open in $X$. 
And we know that $B$ is of the form $ U_1×...U_n×\mathbb R×...$ where each $U_i$ is open in $\mathbb R$.

Applying $F^{-1}$ gives $F^{-1}(B) = {f_ 1}^{-1}(U_1)\cap...\cap {f_ n}^{-1}(U_n)$, Which is open in $X$.

Then it's done.

I'd like to see this argument is false or not. Any commentary will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are missing the point: Munkres is **not** demonstrating continuity when he proves that $U$ open in $X$ implies $F(U)$ open in $\Bbb R^\omega$. He is showing that $F$ is an open map. Also, Munkres already used a very brief version of your argument to show that $F$ is continuous; you may have missed it because he went through it fast.

Comment: @0XLR Thx! now I see the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear that $F$ is continuous as $\pi_n \circ F = f_n$ is continuous for all coordinates $n$ (no need for your extended argument). Munkres hardly mentions it.

What **is** needed is showing that $F$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $f[X] \subseteq \Bbb R^\omega$ and for that we need to show that $F$ is injective/1-1 and that $F[U]$ is open in $f[X]$ (not in $\Bbb R^\omega$, usually) for all open subsets $U$ of $X$.